# Wordpress change user to admin

Tags: wordpress, admin

I am building a wp site and am just about finished. I set up the site with the admin as myself, my email address and avatar. Problem is I need to deliver it with the client as the admin using his name, email and avatar so it is his avatar that shows up as the agent.

Can someone point me to the correct documentation that has dealt with this before or explain the best way to do this ?

Update:

I have added the client as an administrator but I still show up as the agent of the site (super user). This is a real estate site.

Would this be specific to the template I am using (agentpress 2.0) or some sort of setting in all wp sites ?

Comment: Add a user with admin role. That's all.

Comment: [Full documentation](https://codex.wordpress.org/).

Answer (score 0):

If you are do it via PHP [Read this](http://www.joshuawinn.com/create-a-new-wordpress-admin-user-from-php/) else you can add a user with admin privileges.